# CoreData not saving

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PhotoList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var whoTookArray: [String] = []
var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
let moc:NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
var whoTookName: String = ""


func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"PhotoListEntity")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "whoTook", ascending: true)
    request.predicate = nil
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20
    return request
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if let let whoTookName = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? PhotoListEntity {
        cell.textLabel?.text = whoTookName.whoTook
    }
    return cell
}

//NSFetchedResultsController Delegate functions

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type:NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    }
    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        moc?.deleteObject(fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PhotoListEntity)
    case .Insert:
        break
    case .None:
        break
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

}
```

and

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol sendDetailsDelegate {
    func sendDetails(name: String)
}

class Details: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "chooseImage:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageSelected.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        imageSelected.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBOutlet var whoTookTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var imageSelected: UIImageView!
    let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!



    //Pick the image by tapping, accessing the PhotoLibrary
    func chooseImage(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Put the selected image into the screen
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        let pickedImage: UIImage = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
        let smallPicture = scaleImageWith(pickedImage, newSize: CGSizeMake(288,148))
        var sizeOfImageView: CGRect = imageSelected.frame
        sizeOfImageView.size = smallPicture.size
        imageSelected.frame = sizeOfImageView
        imageSelected.image = smallPicture
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func scaleImageWith(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }


    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if whoTookTextField == nil || imageSelected == nil { return }
        if imageSelected == nil { return }

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("PhotoListEntity", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
        let name = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        name.setValue(whoTookTextField.text, forKey: "whoTook")


        if let navigation = self.navigationController {
            navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
}



and this is my CoreData model:



import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(PhotoListEntity)
class PhotoListEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var whoTook: String
    @NSManaged var relationship: PhotoListEntity

}
```

I'm new on this, I'm sorry for anything. I wish to know why this is not being saved when I close and open the app again. Thanks!!!!

Answer already posted! Thanks everyone for the ideas! :D

Comment: I don't see a save of your managed object context anywhere

Comment: How do I save it? I watched a tutorial from Stanford University and there the guy said CoreData autosaves stuff.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the light! Answer on edit.

Comment: It would be better to move that edit to an answer and accept it. It's fine to answer your own question. Otherwise, it'll look like the question still needs to be answered.

Comment: Also I would recommend removing the answer from the question, so it's not confusing as to what the problem was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function:

```
func save() {
        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var whoTook: AnyObject! = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("PhotoListEntity", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
        var error: NSError?
        moc.save(nil)
    }
```

and call it in the addButton! Done! :D